# reversing the direction of a bar chart in C

Tags: c, microcontroller, 68hc12

I want to programme my own version of a variometer to represent the *climb* and *sink* in metres/second.  The values are displayed on to a LCD module screen.  The climb and sink values are scaled down from a potentiometer that I can rotate to change the values while the program is running.  The climb values to be displayed range from `climb: 0  m/s` to `climb: 300  m/s` and the sink values range from `sink: 0  m/s` to `sink: -300  m/s`.  This bit is fine.

What I want to now do is display these in the form of a bar chart with zero point in the centre.  As `climb` increases to 300 the blocks on the right of the zero point are filled accordingly from left to right.  When the `sink` value decreases to -300 I want the blocks on the left hand side of the zero point to fill accordingly from right to left, essentially reversing the direction of the right hand side.

```
   climb = (DELVAL*600ul + 1023/2)/1023;               
   sink =  (DELVAL*600ul + 1023/2)/1023;

   climb2 = ((DELVAL-511.5)*600ul + 1023/2)/1023;                        
   sink2 =  ((DELVAL+511.5)*600ul + 1023/2)/1023;

   if (DELVAL > 511.5)
   {
        sprintf(buf, "Climb: +%d  m/s ", climb-300);                
        lcd_putxy(2,0,buf);
        for (delay = 0; delay < 50000; delay++);                   
   }
   if (DELVAL < 511.5)
   {
        sprintf(buf, "Sink: -%d   m/s ", ~sink+300);                
        lcd_putxy(2,0,buf);
        for (delay = 0; delay < 50000; delay++);
   }
   character1 = climb2 / 35;
   character2 = sink2 / 35;

      lcd_move(1,10);                                  

   for (i = 0; i < character1; i++)                            
   {

      lcd_putchar(0xD0);                                      
   }
      lcd_putstr("  ");                                      

  for (delay = 0; delay < 50000; delay++);            

  lcd_move(1,2);                                      

  for (i = 0; i < character2; i++)                     
  {    
       lcd_putchar(0xD0);         
  } 
   for (delay = 0; delay < 50000; delay++);
```

`DELVAL` is the data read from the potentiometer.  I can get the right hand side of the bar graph to work but I cant get the left hand side working. Can anyone let me know any issues with my code and explain the best method to get the left side working.

The part that is not working in my code is the for loop containing `character2`.

Comment: You need to add some examples of the desired output. For example, at rest (zero climb/sink) you might want `░░░░█░░░░`; at maximum climb `░░░░█████`, and at maximum sink `█████░░░░`. Or something similar. You can copy-paste Unicode [block element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_Elements) or [box drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) characters from the Wikipedia pages. There's StackOverflow [markdown editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) too.

Comment: Which LCD Controller are you using?

Comment: @NominalAnimal the way you have it there is exactly how I want it.  The only difference is the middle zero point takes a bigger block character.  I have the right hand side working but as soon as it enters the left hand `sink` side the LCD displays blocks all over the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't describe what is not working.  But I'm guessing that the left side is drawn from left to right instead of right to left as you intended.  Where did you intend to reverse the direction of the left side?

Try this for reversing the left side.  Note that if you used more descriptive variable names, comments, and fewer magic numbers then your code would be a lot easier to understand.

```
int left_bar_length = character2;
int max_bar_length = 300 / 35;
int left_scale_edge = 2;
int scale_center = left_scale_edge + max_bar_length;

// Move cursor to left end of left bar.
lcd_move(1, scale_center - left_bar_length);                                      

// Draw the left bar.
for (i = 0; i < left_bar_length; i++)                     
{    
     lcd_putchar(0xD0);         
}
```

Comment: Sorry the bar graph on the left hand side starts in the middle and the blocks fill to the left as `DELVAL` is decreased. @kkrambo

Comment: I have edited the question to show the section that is not working @kkrambo

Comment: @user_1 Your loop with character2 does not work because it always starts drawing at `(1, 2)`.  You didn't do anything to reverse the direction.  Your character2 loop draws left to right just like your character1 loop.  The fix I have presented here still technically draws left to right but it doesn't always start at `(1, 2)`.  Instead it starts at `(1, scale_center - left_bar_length)`.  This will give the illusion that it is drawing from right to left because the right edge of the left bar will always be aligned with the center of the scale.

Comment: @user_1 Is the value of `character2` negative?  (I can't tell what you expect from your code.)  My code expects `left_bar_length` to be positive so maybe set it to the absolute value of `character2`.

Comment: no the value of character2 should be positive.  It is just the sink value that I display as negative to give the effect of a decrease in height. @kkrambo

Comment: @user_1 If `character2` is being calculated to the correct value (something between 0 and 8) then I think my fix should work.  But if `character2` is being calculated incorrectly then there is something wrong with your math.  Why are you adding 511.5 to `DELVAL` when calculating `sink2`?  Does that really work like you expect?  Have you stepped through your code in the debugger?

Comment: I have not yet stepped through the code in debugger.  Looking back at it now and doing some manual calculations `DELVAL + 511.5` is not correct.  I done some manual calculations with `DELVAL - 511.5` instead and `sink2` once completely scaled down to `character2`  is equal to -8 (DELVAL at lowest) to 0 (DELVAL at highest (511.5)).  So when it enters my for loop its already below 0 so the for loop does not execute correctly.  So maybe the solution is to invert `sink2` then scale it down to `character2` and follow your suggestion from there. Would this be correct? @kkrambo

Comment: By following the suggesting i am referring to swapping `character2` with `left_bar_length`.

Comment: @user_1 Yes, I suppose that will get you working well enough.  But why are you "inverting" an integer value with the `~` operator?  I don't believe that's the proper way to use that operator and I think it could produce inaccuracies.  You should be using the absolute value method, `abs()`, or just negate the value with `-`.